# Как пишется "не()зачтено?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Не()зачтено пишется вместе или раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Корректно раздельное написание**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE): ***не зачтено.***

Слово ***зачтённый*** -- причастие, ***зачтено*** -- его краткая форма. ***Не*** [с краткими формами причастий](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=78#pp78) пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 2):

В большинстве случаев краткие глагольные формы на НЫЙ (**незачтенный** ответ  - ответ **не зачтен**) являются причастиями и пишутся с НЕ раздельно.

Грамматический анализ следует проводить  **для парных вариантов**, так как некоторые слова на НЫЙ могут являться как причастиями, так и прилагательными  и различаются только  **по смыслу** в различных словосочетаниях,  например: невыдержанный человек – прилагательное, невыдержанный чай – причастие.

Тогда: чай **не выдержан** (причастие) - человек **невыдержан** (прилагательное).